# Filtering through a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

I just began dealing with mathematica and I find it, compared to Python, C++ and C#, very difficult. It feels very complicated to use and not so easy to read. I am dealing with the following problem:

I have the following list:

```
alist={{f[5], g[150], f[36], g[12]}, {f[126], g[178], f[1], g[2]}, {f[20], g[117], f[10], g[200]}, {f[187], g[184], f[11], g[32]}, {f[187], g[149], f[67], g [65]}}
```

Now my first tast is that I need to select the 3rd element in every sub list. A second list contains the differences between the arguments of the first and last entry. The end result should be like this:

```
{{f[36], f[1], f[10], f[11], f[67]}, {-7, 124, -180, 155, 122}}
```

While I understand how I should proceed, I don't know the syntax and it feels that that syntax, changes depending on the case at hand. My initial idea was to somehow identify when we were observing a sub-list and then use a counter, which once it would increment to 3, we would select that element of sublist and Append it to a new one. But the problem is, that the list contains functions evaluated at some arbitrary value (if one can say so) and not numbers, so things such as Flatten etc, don't work in this case

Comment: First task: `alist[[All, 3]]` , Second task: `(Last@First@# - Last@Last@# ) & /@ alist`

Comment: Alternatively, `alist[[All,1,1]]-alist[[All,-1,1]]`.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: @Syed and what about Physics students? Where do I fit in?

Comment: @Syed Thx for the solution, but how can I know that the syntax for the 2nd case it's like the one you wrote? Is there a link you can provide, that explains the syntax and how one can write conditions and loops which ultimately affect the result? In C++ or python, loops and conditions etc are pretty easy to read and understand how they operate. Here in mathematica everything is so complicated

Comment: @imbAF I don't think that the difference between maths and physics matters in this context.

Comment: I was learning a (second) language once and had great difficulty putting sentences together as I was translating from my native language. The two didn't match structurally. My teacher told me to stop translating and that's when I got the hang of it. Regarding your other question about physics, you should know that the inventor of Mathematica (Stephen Wolfram) is a physicist.

Comment: @Syed thank you for your help and answers. Could you help me with one final thing: how to interpret or understand this: "& /@" ?

Answer (score 1):

@imbAF

here is the explanation for `(Last@First@# - Last@Last@# ) & /@ alist`

2 steps:

```
f = (Last@First@# - Last@Last@#)&; (*<-- this is a lambda.*)
f /@ alist
```

in Mathematica, everything is a "List", we use First, Last, [[ ]] to index the elements.

if you are familiar with python, here is the "equivalent".

```py
alist = [[[5], [150], [36], [12]], [[126], [178], [1], [2]]]
f = lambda x: x[0][-1] - x[-1][-1]
for i in alist: print(f(i))
```

that /@ is Map in Mathematica. We use it as a loop.

Comment: Ah I see, so /@ plays the role of a loop, depending on how many elements a list has. One more thing. If I have a nested list that doesn't contain nr. i.e :  alist[{x1, x2, x3, x4} , {a, b, c, d}], how can I generate arrows to change it like this: {x1->a,x2->b,x3->c,x4->d}? Is this index based procedure ?

Comment: @imbAF ```alist[{x1, x2, x3, x4} , {a, b, c, d}] //
Apply[List] // Echo //
MapThread[Rule]``` it's another question, please ask a new question.

Comment: I am trying to do different stuff with a list, like list manipulation, and I am trying a series of different commands. But thanks!

Comment: @imbAF Have you already had a chance to look through the [List Manipulation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html) guide?

Comment: @MarcoB I am curretly looking at that exact page, but I am yet to finish it, and I still haven't encountered things like this: (Last@First@# - Last@Last@# ) & /@ alist
How do I understand this and how do I think of using it for what I want? The problem is how the symbols are connected to each other. I know for example the slash-dot notation. But the & / @ I don't know what it is

Comment: @imbAF For `#` look up [`Function`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html?q=Function), and for `/@` look up [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html?q=Map). You'll need to familiarize yourself with Mathematica's basic syntax.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for the links. One thing I noticed, what's the difference between Thread and Map? Thread, applies a function on the list given as an argument, and Map, does the same no?

Comment: @imbAF they're not quite the same. Take a look at the section on Thread in the [Structural operations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionalOperations.html#31585] guide for some examples.